# What is the flight time from Beirut to Paris using different aircraft?

Tags: airbus-a320, flight-path, boeing-787, time, airbus-neo

If the distance between Beirut and Paris is 1985 miles / 3194.55 km / 1724.92 nautical miles, and a flight using Airbus 320-200 take 4 hours and 40 minutes, how much would it take using the following aircraft:

1. Airbus 321
2. Airbus 330-900 neo
3. Boeing 787-9

And by the way what is the neo word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are of course various factors that play in here but lets look at base numbers

- Airbus 321 Cruise Speed: [515 MPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A321)
- Airbus 330-900 Neo: no cruise data published yet
- Boeing 787-9 Cruise Speed: [561 MPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner)
- Airbus 320-200 Cruise Speed: [514 MPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320_family)

With the above listed speeds rough estimates of travel time would be

- Airbus 321: 3.85 Hours
- Airbus 330-900 Neo: no cruise data published yet
- Boeing 787-9 Cruise Speed: 3.54 Hours
- Airbus 320-200: 3.86 Hours

Lets dig in a bit, you state that the A320 takes 4 hours 40 minutes for the flight but at cruise the numbers are showing 3.86 hours. The above numbers don't account for climb out which will occur at a lower speed and you are flying west which usually means head wind. I would assume your distance number is a point to point number which does not reflect the path a given flight will actually fly. So chances are the A321 which only cruises 1MPH faster than the A320 will take the same 4:40 time. The 787-9 is a bit shy of 10% faster so it will shave about 28 minutes off the flight time if we are comparing total times on a more holistic basis.

---

[As per your second question Neo stands for New Engine Option.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A330neo)

> The [Airbus A330neo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A330neo) ("neo" for "New Engine Option")